# dompdf - strong/th tags issue

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have 2 different fonts, one for normal font and another for bold. I'm trying to apply the bold font to the strong tag but this is ignored.

I've defined the font like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: boldFont;
    src: url("{{ asset('fonts/main/font_bold.ttf') }}") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: regularFont;
    src: url("{{ asset('fonts/main/font_regular.ttf') }}") format('truetype');
}
```

And I've defined the styles:

```
.bold, th, strong {
    font-family: boldFont !important;
}
```

This work for a p tag but not when I use the strong or th tag even if I add the class 'bold' to them:

```
<p class="bold">This Works</p>
<strong>This is ignored</strong>
<strong class="bold">This is ignored</strong>
```

I'm using the package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf version 0.8.5 and Laravel 5.6.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class blod

> `<strong class="bold">This is ignored</strong>`

Answer (score 0):

use span with class instead of strong/b tags for example:

```
<span class="b">awesome</span>
```

Comment: You should explain why this will work, or why the OPs code doesnt work.

Comment: Hey, I don't know why normal <b> tag is not working, but I found this quick fix.